# Different alphabet with \alph

Tags: numbering, languages, alphabet

My language (Slovenian) uses a different alphabet that starts with a, b, c, č, d. I have the correct `babel` settings but `\alph{}` numbering still gives me a, b, c, d.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}

\renewcommand\thesection{\alph{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example redefines `\alph`/`\Alph` according to the [Slovene alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slovenian_alphabet). The original definition of the internals `\@alph` and `\@Alph` can be found in the LaTeX kernel ([source documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}

\renewcommand\thesection{\alph{section}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@alph}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or\v c\or
    d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or
    k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or r\or s\or\v s\or
    t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or
    y\or z\or
    \v z\else\@ctrerr\fi
}
\renewcommand*{\@Alph}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\or A\or B\or C\or\v C\or
    D\or E\or F\or G\or H\or I\or J\or
    K\or L\or M\or N\or O\or P\or R\or S\or\v S\or
    T\or U\or V\or W\or X\or
    Y\or Z\or\v Z\else\@ctrerr\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{\Alph{section}}
\section{\Alph{section}}
\section{\Alph{section}}
\section{\Alph{section}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- Instead of `č` the definition uses the form `\v c`, which is called the LaTeX internal character representation (LICR). It has the advantage that it works independent on the input encoding.
- I would recommend `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with `\usepackage{lmodern}` instead of the old `OT1` font encoding with Computer Modern fonts, where the accented letters are constructed of the base character with the accent. `T1` encoding contains slots for the accented characters and the Latin Modern fonts extends the Computer Modern fonts with many accented characters as single glyphs.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the definition of `\alph` (and the accompanying `\@alph`) in the [LaTeX kernel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\def\alph#1{\expandafter\@alph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@alph#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or
   k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or
    y\or z\else\@ctrerr\fi}
```

`\@alph` conditions on the value of the passed counter using an `\ifcase`...`\fi` statement. You can create your own counter representation this way. I've done so using `\slalph` and `\@slalph` below (with the alphabet taken from [Wikipedia's Slovene alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slovene_alphabet)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}

\makeatletter
\def\slalph#1{\expandafter\@slalph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@slalph#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or č\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or
   k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or r\or s\or š\or t\or u\or v\or 
    z\or ž\else\@ctrerr\fi}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\thesection{\slalph{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}

\end{document}
```

You could do the same with the uppercase alphabet and define (say) `\slAlph` (and `\@slAlph`) accordingly.